# Can't connect mongodb to mongolab

Tags: mongodb, mlab

So I am unable to connect to mongolab inside the mongo shell for some reason. In specifics, when I run `mongo ds041643.mongolab.com:41643/teamsavage -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>` inside the mongo shell, and ofcourse replace the brackets with my proper database credentials, as soon as I hit enter, it brings me to a new line with 3 dots and nothing after that.

I ran through the troubleshooting connections guide found under docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#help to try to figure the problem out and that did not help either.

I followed the guide step-by-step and the following occurred.

- So it first said to ping the mongolab host, and I did with the following:

  ping ds041643.mongolab.com  and successfully got responses back
- I then ran nc -w 3 -v ds041643.mongolab.com 41643 and got the following response back

Connection to ds041643.mongolab.com 41643 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

I am officially stuck with no further documentation to run through to fix my persistent problem. Please help!

Comment: Given the "..." description, it sounds like you might be trying to run the `mongo` shell command line from inside the `mongo` shell. You need to run this from a normal command prompt (windows) or bash/zsh/*sh shell (linux/os x). To connect to MongoLab you should also check that you are running a 3.0 or newer version of the `mongo` shell with `mongo --version`.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-setup-mongodb-in-mongolab/

Comment: If you still need help, please contact support@mongolab.com and we'll get you up and running!

Comment: Thank you Stennie! That worked, I just had to try the same command outside of the mongo shell and it connected beautifully! Thank you for saving me!